# Prevent user from picking the default value in a dropdown menu

Tags: html, forms

I am trying to prevent the user from picking the default dropdown menu option. Is there any way to add  text instead of value in the dropdown menu option? My code:

```
<select name='test'>
<option value='default' selected='selected'>Please select the value</option>
<option value='value1'>value1</option>
<option value='value2'>value2</option>
</select>
```

I don't want the user to pick 'Please select the value' option. Is there better way to to this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Client side code (javascript/HTML) is OK for this, but it's only half the battle.

Since you don't want the user to actually *select* this "default value", this is what I would do:

```
<option value=''>Please select the value</option>
```

Leve the `value` as an empty string. Then in your server side code, check if the value posted was empty or not. There's no point in populating an arbitrary default value if you aren't going to use it.

By default, the first `<option>` will be selected according to standard browser behavior, so you don't really need the`selected` attribute. You *do* need the `value=''` though or the browser can post the text content of the `<option>`.

Comment: The `disabled` attribute could be used but it doesn't actually stop the user from submitting the form without picking a value, so in effect it's the same as this.

Answer (score 3):

You can do

```
<option value='' disabled='disabled' selected='selected'>Please select the value</option>
```

I assume you're using some client-side validation to make sure that this option isn't selected on submit too? This will mean they can't select it once clicked off, but you'll need to validate it.

Something like

```
<script LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
<!-- 
    function ValidateForm(form){ 
    ErrorText= ""; 
    if ( form.test.selectedIndex == 0 ) {
         alert ( "Please select a value" ); 
         return false; 
    } 
    if (ErrorText= "") { 
        form.submit()
    } 
} 
-->
</script>
```

Then on your submit button

```
<input type="button" name="SubmitButton" value="Submit" onClick="ValidateForm(this.form)">
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use JavaScript to check for the selected value when the user submits the form. If the value="default", warn the user.

Answer (score 0):

```
    <select name='test'>
<option value='default' selected='selected' enabled='false'>Please select the value</option>
<option value='value1'>value1</option>
<option value='value2'>value2</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Edited for a more suitable solution

Answer (score 0):

When Using Html Helper,make value field of Select that is default value as empty

```
 @Html.DropDownListFor(Model => Model.Value, new List<SelectListItem>() { new SelectListItem { Text = "Select", Value = "" }, new SelectListItem { Text = "Value1", Value = "Value1" }, new SelectListItem { Text = "Value2", Value = "Value2" } }, new { @required = "required"})
```